# How to disable a linting rule inline in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, inline, lint, disable

Is there a way to disable a linting rule for a line in flutter?

I have a specific use case where I want to disable linting for two lines. 
I have a lot of business logic already written so I cannot change the code.

```dart
abstract class ReviewName {
  static final NEW = 'NEW';
  static final OLD = 'OLD';
}
```

The above code will have linting errors: Name non-constant identifiers using lowerCamelCase.dart(non_constant_identifier_names)

Is there any way I avoid the lint error for only the two lines?

Answer (score 96):

#### General answer

To ignore a single **line**, you can add a comment above the line:

```dart
// ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
final NEW = 'NEW';
```

To ignore for the whole **file**, you can add a comment at the top of the file:

```dart
// ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names
```

To ignore for the whole **project**, you can [set the rule to false](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#disabling-individual-rules) in your *analysis_options.yaml* file:

```yaml
include: package:lints/recommended.yaml

linter:
  rules:
    non_constant_identifier_names: false
```

#### See also

- [Customizing static analysis](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options)
- [Setting up Lint Rules in Dart-Flutter](https://medium.com/podiihq/setting-up-lint-rules-in-dart-flutter-1ebbed0418a6)

Comment: Where might this file reside?

Comment: @RichardHaven, The analysis_options.yaml file should be in the root of your project. If it doesn't already exist, you can create it.

Answer (score 28):

Use the `// ignore:` syntax, for example:

```
abstract class ReviewName {
  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  static final NEW = 'NEW';

  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  static final OLD = 'OLD';
}
```

The list of rule names is [here](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/).

Comment: I found the documentation here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#excluding-code-from-analysis

Comment: I would wish for something more global. I love snake_case, but dart community disagree.

Comment: The OP wanted just two lines. The global way is to change `analysis.yaml`. Where possible try to respect the community conventions for code readability.

Comment: Any way just add one //ignore for the whole class? If I have 50 static strings I don't wanna add extra 50 comments.